# What CMS framework besides WordPress can I use to help me create child pages or categories that have multiple parents?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, parent-child

I'm attempting to build a small gallery site with WordPress, where there are several child galleries involved. Some of the galleries need to belong to more than one "parent". For example, if I have a gallery with the name "Davis", and multiple parents "Mom" and "Dad", I want to set it up so that both the URLs "mywebsite.com/mom/davis" and "mywebsite.com/dad/davis" go to the same gallery page. The trick is, I can't seem to be able to do this is WordPress without creating "Davis" twice, either as a post or page, which is not at all what I want to do. I'm trying to keep the site as lightweight as possible and I want to avoid duplicating content and other bad practices.

I'm a beginner to PHP but I was wondering if you fine folks knew of another small CMS or PHP framework out there that might support this type of structure. I've looked into Drupal but it seems too bulky for my needs. Would there be a lightweight framework that's simple enough to pick up rather quickly? I'm a pretty fast learner, but don't have a lot of experience with these types of customizations, although I do understand the concepts involved.

A little more info about the site, it has four main "parent" galleries and about 20 "child" galleries. I'm hoping to use an FTP solution for image uploading, so the CMS only needs to handle the permalink structure, a few page templates and styling. It should also be relatively SEO-friendly.

Also, if somebody does know how to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish in WordPress, that would be great too. I'm not opposed to using WordPress in general as I've used it several times before, it's just that I've done my research and nobody seems to have a solution to the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at a microframework called [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/).

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking into it now, seems very lightweight which is a nice feature, and also seems to be great at generating URLs. The documentation leaves a bit to be desired, though. I suppose I'll have to delve into it a bit further before I know if it's the right solution.

Comment: Also, how would an admin interface on something like this be set up? I was hoping to avoid configuring one of those...

Comment: This is a framework, not a CMS, so making the admin panel is up to you. If you want all that out of the box, you should consider a CMS. I'd suggest Drupal.

Comment: Drupal is a better CMS

Answer (score 0):

What requirement you have posted , can be done in WordPress.

Create to category there - Mom and Dad.

Then create a page for gallery Davis and select both categories for Davis.